# Magento 2: How to display the all product review and rating on Home Page?

Tags: magento2, review, product-review

How to display all product **reviews and ratings** on the home page like below image?[image]

Comment: what you tried so far? Please at least give some try.

Answer (score 1):

add custom block template to your home page and add below code into phtml file

```
    <?php
        $_helper    = $this->helper('your_cusotm_helper_name');        
        foreach($_helper->getAllReviews() as $review):?>
            <div class='review-single col-md-12'>
                <?php echo $review['title']; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

helper >> `data.php`

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $reviewCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->reviewCollectionFactory = $reviewCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function getAllReviews()
    {
        $reviewsCollection = $this->reviewCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addStoreFilter($this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId())
            ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
            ->setDateOrder();
        return $reviewsCollection;
    }
```